# all type phone number regex in json file and working on angular 6

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, console

Need those type of phone number use in json file, 
Check and validate phone number using regex.

- (123) 456-7890
- (123) 456 7890
- (123)456-7890
- 123-456-7890
- 123.456.7890
- 1234567890
- +31636363634
- 075-63546725

Alrady use those regex pattern :

- /^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
- /^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/

Both pattern working on regex editor, console but not support json file and not use a double forward slash (//)

Error: pattern.json file
[json] Invalid escape character in string.

```
{
        "name": "phone",
        "title": "Phone",
        "isCurrent": true,
        "isStable": true,
        "group": "advance",
        "isForTable": true,
        "validation": { 
            "minLength": 2,
            "maxLength": 50,
            "pattern": "/^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/",


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a string pattern, without regex delimiters, keeping in mind that backslashes should be doubled:

```
"validation": { 
        "minLength": 2,
        "maxLength": 50,
        "pattern": "^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$",
}
```

Comment: not use a double forward slash (//) 
because they have not understand

Comment: @VatsalDashani But the [regex works](https://regex101.com/r/JBKUVh/1) and the syntax is correct.

Comment: I understand your regex works  but this ans is not helping my case

Comment: @VatsalDashani Please add the sample input JSON to the question. My validation shows "No errors found. JSON validates against the schema". *Not helping my case* feedback does not explain what exactly does not work for you. Clarify *what* does not work, *how* it does not work, and *how* it *should* work.